# How to update mysql database using Email?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, email

I am new in php. I have scenario in which i want to `update mysql database` through an `email.`

**Description**

I have a form on my web application. When user fill that form and `click on submit` button then data is saved in `Database` and here i want that the `Link of Form` is also send by `email` on clicking on `submit button` to the `manager` for approval. In Email there is some contant or form which is filled by `user` and a button for `Approve` and `Re-Submit`.

Here If Manger Click on `Approve` Button then my database is updated by the status of `Approved by manager` and also send an email to user in reply and another email send for Approval to Organization `Unit Head`

Then Here is the same scenario. Here form is display in email which is filled by user and have two buttons `Approve` and `Re-Submit` If `Unit Head` click on `Approve` Then data should be update in Db and send a mial to `manager` and `user` also.

**Is it Possible, And how i can do it. Please suggest me some helpful refrences**

Comment: just put a link on that mail with a parameter....

Comment: As ShiiguriAnemone said, you will have to do with with a link to a php file that does your desired functionality, a form / other extensive actions are not possible from within a e-mail as most e-mail hosters / providers disable these kind of things due to security reasons.

Comment: @Epodax You mean it is not possible to do this an email. In email i cannot display form and not perform any sql update

Comment: No, it is not possible to do this in a email directly, you can, as said before, add a link with a parameter to a php file that does the desired functionality.

Comment: @Epodax you mean i add a link on a button in email and when manager is click on this button it will redirect to desired link

Comment: Yes... That is what I mean.

Comment: @sunny otherwise your mail will be flagged as spam...

Answer (score 0):

When user submit data you are saving data in database table and sending email to manager to approve it you can achieve this by following below steps.

1) when user submit form save data in database table add one filed in database table to indicate this entry is approve or not you will get last inserted id of that record.

2) send mail to manager with link to approve user data by yourscriptpath ? id = {inserted id}

3) create script as you have specified in approve link put your logic in that script

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_$_REQUEST['id']) {
    // check record exist with this id in databse
    //if record exist in databse change your approve flag to approve  
    // send approve mail to user you will get user detials from that id
    //redirect to success page    
}
```

Hope this will help